# replace values in pandas based on aggregion and condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to replace values in **col1** with a specific value (ex:with "b"). I should count the records of each group based on col1 and col2. For example count of **col1 = a, col2 = t is 3** and **col1 = a, col2 = u is 1** .

If the count is greater than 2 then replace the value of col1 with 'b'. For this example, i want to replace all "a" values with "b" where col2 = t.

I tried the below code, but it did not change all of then "a" values with this condition.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('c:/test.xlsx')
df.loc[df[(df['col1'] == 'a') & (df['col2'] == 't')].agg("count")["ID"] >2, 'col1'] = 'b'
```

I want this result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` and check whether all your conditions are satisfied. If yes, replace the values in col1 with b, and otherwise leave the values as is:

```
import numpy as np
df['col1'] = np.where((df['col1']=='a') & 
                      (df['col2']=='t') & 
                      (df.groupby('col1')['ID'].transform('count') > 2),'b',df['col1'])
```

prints:

```
   ID col1 col2
0   1    b    t
1   2    b    t
2   3    b    t
3   4    a    u
4   5    b    t
5   6    b    t
6   7    b    u
7   8    c    t
8   9    c    u
9  10    c    w
```

Using `transform('count')`, will check whether the grouped (by col1) ID column will have more than 2 values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.